# What does semi-colon mean in function parameters?

Tags: statistics, functions

Like this one:
[image]

Why can't they just use $F(k,n,p)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it distinguishes the value $k$ of the random variable $X$ in the pmf $P(X=k)=F(k;\,n,\,p)-F(k-1;\,n,\,p)$ from the distribution's parameters. For functions that don't characterise probability distributions, semicolons can have another use in grouping arguments in which a function is symmetric, such as [the hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series) being symmetric only when a particular pair of its four arguments are exchanged.

Comment: Okay, so it doesn't affect the function itself, and if I create my own function, I can place semi-colon anywhere I feel parameter separation is necessary?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus It's recommended to use it in the ways described above. For example, $f(x,\,y,\,z):=x+2y+3z$ shouldn't have a mix of commas and semicolons, and we prefer to avoid semicolons in this case, so it should just use commas.